# Find angle of rotation to orient one vector to another if axis is known

Tags: 3d, three.js, linear-algebra

I want to rotate a vector, shown in green, so that it is oriented to another vector (also green), into the position shown by the red dotted line. You can think of the vector to rotate as lying on a circle or disc. I have the axis of rotation already (in blue). What are the steps required to find the angle by which to rotate the circle?

[image]

Also, is there a name for this kind of relationship? I don't want the vectors to be "parallel" exactly, just for them to appear to line up when looking straight down the axis of rotation. You might find this called an "up" vector in 3D graphics, and when the "up" vector is always the Y-axis things are simple. I want to find a generalized solution for any two arbitrary vectors.

ps. I'm trying to do this in three.js.

Comment: You say that the up vector (dark green) and rotation axis (blue) are given as vectors. How is the light green line given? Can you elaborate more on what you're trying to do? More information would be helpful :)

Comment: Sorry for vagueness – they're all vectors. I've tried to clarify in the question text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that

1. the circle is on a plane S, its normal is parallel to the rotation axis (blue),
2. the up vector and the axis define a plane P,
3. the red line is on P,
4. and the green line is on S.

Using the dot product we can project the up vector on S to get a vector V on S that is parallel to the red line. Then we can compute the angle between V and the green line. In three.js this can be achieved like this:

```js
// compute projection v
var n = axis.clone().normalize(); // normal of S plane
var d = up.dot(n); // distance from up vector to S plane
var v = up.clone().sub(n.multiplyScalar(d)); // maybe -d

// compute angle
var angle = green.angleTo(v);
```

d or -d depends on the direction of the axis. Note that this does not work if up vector and axis are parallel.